# :updateall command to update all files

Tags: save

There's a `:w` and a `:wall` command but there's only an `update` command, there isn't a `:updateall` command.

Why isn't there one and how would you implement it in `vimscript` and `lua` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:wa[ll]     Write all changed buffers.  Buffers without a file
            name cause an error message.  Buffers which are
            readonly are not written.
```

In fact, `wall` does `update` for all buffers, and not `write`. So "update all" is there. Actually, it is "write all" that is missing, but it looks that no one really wants it.

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't there one?

Because no one sent that patch to the core team.

> how would you implement it in `vimscript`?

I would do `:bufdo up` and call it a day.